# Is it possible to use pgsql2shp utility in PL/pgsql environment?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I intend to use PL/pgSQL to generate calculation points on streets with respect to address locations. I am aware that using pgsql2shp utility, a shapefile can be generate using postgis query.

I was wondering whether is it possible to use pgsql2shp utility in PL/pgSQL functions?

What I need to do is to:

1) first generate the shapefile of calculation points using shp2pgsql utility on the go in plpgsql

2) then use this shapefile for some geo-processing in the same plpgsql environment for example using ST_DWithin() or ST_Distance() etc.

Comment: What do yu mean by "calculation points". Why do you need to export to a shapefile?

Comment: I am pretty sure you cannot call external functions from within plpgsql -- transactions and security being two reasons -- though you might be able to using pythonu and exec, ie, from a python stored procedure. You would, in my opinion, be much better off doing this from the shell from where you can call Postgres procs via psql, in combination with other exes, like pgsql2shp.

Comment: @Micha: Calculation points are the interpolated point features on nearest streets. They have been computed using ST_ClosestPoint(). I need to export these point features as a shapefile and then use this shapefile to do further geo-processing.

Comment: I think we are confused since you mention shapefile and then  geo-processing. A shapefile is external to PostGIS, so you will need to do your processing in some other GIS software. Is that the intention? Can you be more specific what further geo-porcessing you need? Maybe there's a straight forward solution within PostGIS.

Comment: @Micha: Well, I have three tables in postgres DB i.e., address, street and configurations. Using ST_ClosestPoint(), I interpolated points to the nearest streets (assigned as calculation points). Now, preferably I wanted to save these "calculation points" as a shapefile first and put it in postgres DB on the go and then with reference to this new calculation points table, I wanted to extract some column values from configuration table. But, since you indicated it is not possible to call external functions from within plpgsql, is there any alternative way to do what I need?

Comment: Geo-processing specifically refers to use of ST_DWithin() and ST_Distance in postgis environment.
Example:
Use of ST_DWithin(calc_point.geom, configurations.geom, 50.0) to select features from configurations table (within 50 m) based on new calculation points.
Yes, I am using QGIS but only for the visualization of query results.

Comment: This question is so confusing that I suggest you close it and ask one or two specific questions. In the future, please edit your question rather than adding details to your question(s) in the comment space.